# Facebook feed parameter "properties" not working on using C# SDK

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using Facebook C# SDK 6.0.20 and posting to facebook (Server Side Flow) like this.

```
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = message;
parameters.description = description;
parameters.link = url;
parameters.name = url;
parameters.picture = smallImage;
parameters.caption = "www.mysite.com";
parameters.properties = new
{
    text = joinPrompter,
    href = url
};
parameters.actions = new
{
    name = joinPrompter,
    link = url
};
var api = new FacebookClient
{
    AccessToken = accessToken,
    AppId = ClientID,
    AppSecret = ClientSecret
};
result = api.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

All is well except the properties I am passing. It gets displayed in the post at the end as

> text: Join now!
>   href: http://www.mysite.com

What could be wrong with my post to me/feeds?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `properties` parameter is used only when uploading a video.  `Properties - "A list of properties for an uploaded video, for example, the length of the video"`.  [Taken from here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Comment: I think what you wanted to do is have some links at the bottom of the post (similar to the "like" and "comment" links).  For this you use the `actions` parameter (which you are already using).

Comment: @Lix: this is where Facebook documentation gets sparse. see here.http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ "A JSON object of key/value pairs which will appear in the stream attachment beneath the description, with each property on its own line. Keys must be strings, and values can be either strings or JSON objects with the keys text and href."

Comment: Ah yes - but you see you are now talking about the feed **dialog**.  The method you outlined in your post did not involve a dialog.  It was simply posting directly to their API - no user interaction...  I would imagine that there are some differences when using the two methods...

Comment: I should mention also that I have zero knowledge in C#... Only knowledge (from personal experience) about their API...

Comment: @Lix: Thanks Lix. I suspect its an SDK bug. Maybe Prabir or Nathan will be able to help me out if they are not too busy. :)

Comment: updated title. thanks once more

Comment: No problem - but I think your question now is misleading.  Your title specifies a dialog but your code doesn't reflect that.  Perhaps you want to look into the JavaScript SDK - that is a much easier way to display Facebook dialogs to your users...

Answer (score 2):

Actually properties should be JSON encoded prior to publishing.

```
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
jsonArray.Add(new {
  text = joinPrompter,
  href = url
});

parameters.properties = jsonArray.ToString();
```

This is sample using [SimpleJson](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json) which is internally used in [facebook-c#-sdk](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk).

Or you can simply use something like:

```
parameters.properties = '[{"text":"Some text", "href":"http://example.com"}]';
```

**Update:**
Seems that you may use `IList<object>` and it should be encoded automatically by Facebook C# SDK:

```
IList<object> properties = new IList<object>();
properties.Add(new {
  text = joinPrompter,
  href = url
});
parameters.properties = properties;
```

Comment: thank you for this. i would really like to mark this as answer. but it fetched me a cleaner solution without yet another third party dependency :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with the wonderful Facebook C# SDK. The problem was with the way I used it. `properties` should be used like this

```
parameters.properties = new {
    URL = new
    {
        text = joinPrompter,
        href = url
    }
};
```